# Matrix valued Pythagorean Triples

Tags: matrices, pythagorean-triples

Consider any nxn matrices A, B and C such that
A^2 + B^2 = C^2
Then the matrix triple (A,B,C) is called a Matrix valued Pythagorean Triple.

I have observed that any nxn matrix M and N such that MN=NM, then I can extend Euclid's Fomula to generate a matrix Pythagorean triples, that is

A = M^2 - N^2
B = 2MN
C = M^2 + N^2

Another method to generate Matrix Pythagorean triple was discussed by John D. Cook at his cite, johndcook.com. (im sorry, i dont know how to insert links)

However, the matrices A,B and C mention above are commutative to each other.

My question is how can I generate matrix valued Pythagorean triple (A,B,C) such that A,B and C do not commute to each other?

Another condition is that the matrices A,B and C must not be symmetric matrices

Here's one example;
Let
A = 
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    30 & 13 \\
    3 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

B =
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    4 & 8 \\
    12 & 16 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

C =
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -26 & -25 \\
    -15 & 4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then A^2 + B^2 = C^2.

Please help me, ma'am and sir,  to find a method to generate such noncommutative and nonsymmetric Matrix valued Pythagorean triples.

Comment: Solutions  of  $A^k  +  B^k =  C^k$  in $ n  x  n$  integral  matrices”,  
American  Mathematical Monthly ,  75,  1968, 759-760

Comment: What Pythagorean triple is represented  your example matrices? What do you mean by non-commutative? It is fairly easy to find triples for almost any criteria but your criteria are not specified clearly. Can you show examples?

Answer (score 0):

On Matrix Pythagorean Triples.
American Mathematical Monthly, Volume 126, 2019, issue 2, pp 158- 160.
Abstract
We present a parametrization for the Pythagorean matrices, i.e., integer-valued matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A^2+B^2=C^2$.